# i have an assignment my lecturers give to me, but i really dont have any idea about this

Tags: java

Write a program that prompts the user to enter a symbol '@' and print n times of the symbol '@'
the problem can be defined recursively as follows:

```
If (times=0)
    return 0 
if (times >= 1)
{
    call PRintSymbol (symbol, times-1)
}
```

Comment: Hint is there itself in the problem statment

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: It's always a good question when it also contains the answer.

Comment: If your problem is solved mark  answer as accepted so that it will not list in unanswered section

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CountSymbols {

/**
 * @param args
 */
 static void printsymbols(String inp,String sym){
     int count=0;
     Pattern p=Pattern.compile(sym);
     Matcher m=p.matcher(inp);
     while(m.find()){
         count++;
     }
     System.out.println(sym+" has "+ count+" times");
 }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the Symbol");
    String sym=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the String");
    String inp=in.nextLine();
    CountSymbols.printsymbols(inp,sym);

 }

}
```

Output:
Enter the Symbol

@

Enter the String

i@ the @ inp@ str@ing

@ has 4 times

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "@@Test@@String@lol@lol";
        System.out.println("String: \"" + string +"\" found \'@\' " + //

                (string.length() - string.replaceAll("@", "").length()) //

                + " times."); //
    }
}
```

Explanation: We're given a string S with N characters that we're looking for. We're **getting the difference** between the length of S and length of S (with '@' **replaced by nothing**). Thus we're eliminating all '@'s.

Output:

```
String: "@@Test@@String@lol@lol" found '@' 6 times.
```